# cannot call member function 'Image* Source::GetOutput()' without object, cannot make it static

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class defined as such:

```
// source.C

#include "source.h"

Image* Source::GetOutput()
{
    return this->img;
}




// source.h

#include "image.h"

#ifndef SOURCE_H
#define SOURCE_H

class Source
{
    private:
        Image* img;
    public:
        Image* GetOutput(); 
        virtual void Execute()=0;
};
#endif
```

I need to call `Image img = *Sink::GetOutput();` or something to that effect in a subclass of `Source` . However, that raises the errror `cannot call member function ‘Image* Source::GetOutput()’ without object`. I know that I could make `GetOutput()` static to get rid of this error, but then I would no longer be able to return `this->img;`. Is there any way I can modify this code to have the intended purporse?

Comment: "something to that effect in a subclass of Source" - what does it mean? what is `Sink`?

Comment: You'd could make both `GetOutput` and `img` static.

Comment: Why don't you have an object of type `Sink` and call `GetOutput()` of that?

Comment: @RakibulHasan: The subclass reads a PNM file, so I need to access a pointer to the image. Sink holds written images.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: I tried that, still have the same issue.

Comment: @clcto: The specifications of the project call specifically to take the output from `Source`.

Comment: This is really, really poor design. You should *never* pass references (or pointers) to member variables to outside callers. *Especially* not if they are `private`, as it simply defeats the whole concept of information hiding / encapsulation. As the setup is so poor, and it does not become clear what your code is actually trying to achieve, it's not easy to point out a better design. FUBAR, really. (Fu... erm, broken beyond repair.) This is also called a "XY problem": You ask for a solution for Y, but your *problem* is that you're trying to work around issue X, which you didn't show.

Comment: @DevSolar: It seems that OP is not understanding OOP at all given this question. Talking about good design is a bit too high I think.

Comment: @gexicide: Jeez, I didn't see that other question. You are probably right... Generally speaking, if you're a beginner and you're passing pointers around, chances are excellent you haven't understood the concepts yet. (You start *without* using pointers, and once you get to them, you allocate them in constructors and deallocate them in destructors, but you don't pass naked pointers around until you *really* got the hang of it.)

Comment: Please show the definition of `Sink` and how you're trying to call `GetOutput()`.